# Date Deserialization in Net Core 2

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, asp.net-core-2.0

After converting our app from .NET framework running on a Windows server to be a .NET core 2.0 app running in Linux on Docker, the way dates get deserialized appears to have changed. For example if I had a class:

```cs
public class MyTestClass
{
    public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }
}
```

Which in turn had a controller method:

```cs
public bool DoSomethingWithADate([FromBody] MyTestClass testClass)
{
    return true;
}
```

And I sent through to that end point (with content type "application/json"):

```
{
    "someDate": "2017-10-25T10:00+11:00"
}
```

C# would tell me that the date is the *24th of October 2017 at 11:00pm* - it has subtracted the eleven hours specified in the `+11:00` portion of the someDate string. It has, in effect, converted it to UTC, but the "Kind" of the date is "Local". When run in .NET framework instead of core, the date comes through as *10am on the 25th*, which is

**a)** what I would expect, and

**b)** what we need to keep as we can't affect existing dates coming through from our API users.

How can I set the date not to be converted when deserialising? I have tried the four different options of `SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling` and all that appears to do is affect the "Kind" portion of the C# date. Also setting `SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat;` has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` has no concept of time zones - use `DateTimeOffset` instead, you'll save yourself a lot of headache in the long run. Instead of the `Kind` property, it always needs to have an explicit `Offset` of type `TimeSpan`.

Comment: At this stage I'm not certain that's a change we can make to our API. The question remains though - how can you get the date to stop adding/subtracting the hours offset passed through and to just take the date as is from the JSON passed in?

Comment: You can't, really, without also passing timezone metadata yourself or making assumptions about time zones (the latter being a bad idea in general). Using DateTimeOffset is generally a pretty trivial change to make, as it supports everything DateTime does. If you're exposing this in a JSON API, your users likely already expect you to be using an ISO8601 date format, typically, so changing to DateTime is likely not only safe, but _necessary_.